# What does this C value mean?

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I am working on a university assignment where I have to do different calculations based on the value of a Signal. If C has the value 00 ,I have to return the sum of a and b and also OVF must be 1 if overflow happened.

The code was really basic :

temp <= ('0'&a)+('0'&b);

Result <= temp(3 downto 0);

OVF <= temp(4);

[image]

Yet ,I somehow did something wrong .My issue is that vivado keeps showing me a value called C instead of the actual value of the vector. What does C mean? It's not included in any of the slides of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can better understand some signal values in Vivado simulator if they display in a different radix format than the default, for instance, **binary values** instead of **hexadecimal values**.

AFAIK, the default radix in Vivado simulator is **Hexadecimal** unless you
override the radix for a specific object.
Supported radix values in Vivado Simulator are as following:

- **Binary**,
- **Hexadecimal**,
- **Octal**,
- **ASCII**,
- **Signed** and **Unsigned** decimal.

Therefore I think, here the `C` value indicates **hexadecimal** value.